# How to add "Use Default Value" checkbox for custom form field

Tags: magento2, adminform

I have created a form by exending `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic` class in my class.

I am adding a field using `$fieldset->addField()` to my form for which I need to add "Use Default Value" checkbox field like below screenshot.

[image]

With `dataProvider` class in `ui_component` form, this is done by setting

```
'arguments' => [
    'data' => [
        'config' => [
            'dataType' => 'text',
            'formElement' => 'input',
            'componentType' => 'field',
            'label' => 'Field',
            'validation' => [
                'validate-digits' => true,
            ],
            /* 
             * Below line of code adds the checkbox which
             * Enable/Disable input field when checked 
             */
            'service' => [
                'template' => 'ui/form/element/helper/service',
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Any idea on how to set it for my `addField` function? I have tried it adding as a config parameter but its not working.

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'field',
    'text',
    [
        'name' => 'field',
        'label' => __('Field'),
        'title' => __('Field'),
        'required' => true,
        'service' => [
            'template' => 'ui/form/element/helper/service',
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: where is this field displayed?

Comment: @ShawnAbramson, Its in my admin panel custom form.

Comment: please share full code.

Comment: @Himanshu, I added the complete code for ui_component form field. Its working with ui_component form but not with generic forms

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'field',
    'checkboxes',
    [
        'name' => 'field',
        'label' => __('Field'),
        'title' => __('Field'),
        'required' => true,
        'values' => [['value'=>'1', 'label'=> 'Use Default Value']],
        'checked' =>array(1)
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thank you Himanshu for the answer. If you have ever seen "Use default value" checkbox in Magento admin, it is connected to another field. When the checkbox is checked, the field uses default value and is disabled. When we uncheck the checkbox, the field gets enabled and you can change its value. Its not a separate checkbox field I want to add.